# Why this 2D vector cause the segment fault(core dumped)

Tags: c++, vector, size

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
    a[0] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    a.push_back({12,123,123,1,3,1,23});
    size_t size = a.size();
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
}
```

g++ compiler passed this program , but this error comes when I run it

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

How to solve it? How to count all the elements in this 2D vector?

Comment: You access elements only when the vector has allocated storage in that particular area. `a[0]` accesses an uninitialized part of the storage for `a`, thus causing a segmentation fault. You have to use `push_back` to insert a new element, then you can do `a[0]` with no problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here `a[0] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` you access the `std::vector` at index `0`, but there is no `std::vector` at index `0`, so you access memory you don't own, which results in a segmentation fault! You have to allocate the space first (using `resize`), or use `push_back`, like the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the first row when you create the vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a{{1,2,3,4,5}};
    a.push_back({12,123,123,1,3,1,23});
    size_t size = a.size();
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
}
```